# wp_set_object_terms being undone

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to set some object terms on a Woocommerce product when it is saved. My code is as follows.

```
add_action('set_object_terms', 'update_attributes_after_save', 99, 3);
function update_attributes_after_save($post_id, $terms, $tt_ids, $term_type, $append, $old_tt_ids){
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;

    // If this is a revision, get real post ID
    if ( $parent_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) return;

    $stock_types = array();

    remove_action('set_object_terms', 'update_attributes_after_save', 99, 3);
    $term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms($post_id, array('test-1', 'test-2'), 'pa_in-stock', false);

    error_log("CURRENT TERMS: " . print_r(wp_get_object_terms((string)$post_id, 'pa_in-stock'), true));

    if ( is_wp_error( $term_taxonomy_ids ) ) {
        error_log('success');
    } else {
        error_log('failure');
    }

    return $post_id;
}
```

The first error_log shows the correct values and "success" is also logged. However, when I am redirected back to the product form it shows the original values.

If I put `exit;` in my function and then check the database values, they seem to be correct, so I'm assuming another hook is overwriting the values I'm giving it.

Any clues would be appreciated!